# Office Web Apps opening after being disabled in Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, office-integration, office-web-apps, office

Some, not all, of our users are being forced to open Documents, Spreadsheets, PDFs, and what not in Office Web Apps even after the **Library Tools | Library | Library Settings | General Settings | Advanced Settings | Opening Documents in the Browser** has been configured to "Open in the client application".

Now these folks are using modern browsers and are on Office 2010 in most cases. Some of them it works as expected whilst others it does not work.

My question is two part.

1. What would cause this behavior for some users and not for others?
2. Why do PDFs open in the Word App no matter what the Library settings are? This is affecting all of our users and not just a select group. We don't want it turned off for the whole server but, certain libraries we do.

Comment: It could be something as simple as a browser caching issue. Try asking 1 or 2 or your users to clear their browser cache to test if that is it.

Comment: @DanielZiga I made that recommendation but it doesn't seem to help the issue. Which makes me think it is a browser / version / office compatibility issue?

Answer (score 1):

Is this happening with sp 2010 or 2013?

Some very odd things happen whenOffice 12010 runds against sp 2013 or office 365.

The official MS response is "run Office 2010 service patch 2 to fix it all..

Comment: Thanks. This jogged my memory that I had run the Service Pack myself on my own version of Office. I'll have one of our users test to see if it fixes their issue. On a side note though, this doesn't fix PDFs always opening in OWA.